# Interpret the Doc2Vec Vectors Clusters Representation

Tags: text-mining, word2vec, doc2vec

I am new to Doc2Vec, please bear with the naive questions.

I have generated Doc2vector score i.e. using the 'Paragraph Vector' algorithm.
I have an array output for each document.

I use the model.similar for doc1 and get the output - doc5 and doc10 are similar to doc1.

Q1) How to summarize using the code what are the important words or high-level summary this document holds?

In addition, If I use the array output and run K- means to get 5 clusters. How to define the cluster definition.

Q2) I can read the documents but the number of documents is very high and doing a manual read to find the cluster definition is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in 'summarization' function for `Doc2Vec` doc-vectors (or clusters of same).

Theoretically, the model could do something that's sort-of the opposition of doc-vector inference. It could take a doc-vector – perhaps one corresponding to a existing document – and then provide it to the model, run the model "forward", and read out the activation levels of all its output nodes. At least in models using the default negative-sampling, those nodes map one-to-one with known vocabulary words, and you could plausibly sort/scale those activation levels to find the top-N "most-associated" words with that doc-vector.

You could look at the `predict_output_word()` method source of `Word2Vec` to get a rough idea of how such a calculation could work:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/3514d3fb9224280edd8ddd14c46b722220df5436/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L1131

As mentioned, this isn't an existing capability, and I don't know of an online source for code to do such a calculation. But, if it were implemented, it would be a [welcome contribution](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2459).

(I'm not sure what your `Q2` question actually is.)

Comment: thank you for sharing the information, really appreciate it.